# Update can't see records just committed by another connection

Tags: mysql, transaction

I am performing a transaction using a connection. Whenever a second connection immediately tries to update the rows just inserted, the rows are not found. Even if the transaction was committed before issuing an UPDATE.

I have the mysql query log which describes the scenario.

The last statement fails with 0 rows affected (`UPDATE refresh_token...`) :

```
2018-08-03T13:31:24.829038Z  1150 Query START TRANSACTION
2018-08-03T13:31:24.830026Z  1150 Prepare   INSERT INTO account (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.830493Z  1150 Execute   INSERT INTO account (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.831345Z  1150 Close stmt
2018-08-03T13:31:24.833228Z  1150 Prepare   INSERT INTO refresh_token (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.833666Z  1150 Execute   INSERT INTO refresh_token (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.834356Z  1150 Close stmt
2018-08-03T13:31:24.834477Z  1150 Prepare   INSERT INTO another (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.835155Z  1150 Execute   INSERT INTO another (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.835621Z  1150 Close stmt
2018-08-03T13:31:24.835747Z  1150 Query COMMIT
2018-08-03T13:31:24.840374Z  1150 Prepare   UPDATE refresh_token SET accessed = ? WHERE token = ?
2018-08-03T13:31:24.840799Z  1150 Execute   UPDATE refresh_token SET accessed = '<redacted>' WHERE token = '<redacted>'
2018-08-03T13:31:24.843346Z  1150 Close stmt
```

If I wait 500ms before issuing the `UPDATE refresh_token SET...`, the record is found.

Here is the transaction isolation level:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;
'REPEATABLE-READ', 'REPEATABLE-READ'
```

Comment: What was the setting of  `autocommit` when the `UPDATE` was run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more (like the query execution plan, number of rows affected, indexing, etc.) it will be hard to provide a concise answer. But REPEATABLE_READ raises a flag, at least for me.

Transaction isolation levels are a matter of give-and-take. None of them are "the best"; rather, you choose one that's a "best fit". Each one comes with a cost. If you want high consistency, you get less concurrency.

I like this post:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels/

This excerpt from the post sums it up nicely:

> In REPEATABLE READ every lock acquired during a transaction is held
>   for the duration of the transaction.
>
> In READ COMMITTED the locks that did not match the scan are released
>   after the STATEMENT completes.

Comment: OK turns out the granularity of the `DATETIME` column is in seconds. So inserting with `NOW()` and only updating the `DATETIME` column again with `NOW()` within 1 second makes the record appear as exactly the same, so mysql reports `0 rows updated`. I will accept your answer since you took the time to try to help. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier - As a partial answer, you can use `DATETIME(6)` and `NOW(6)` to get microsecond resolution.